# InfluxQL - Count Occurences of Distinct Values

Tags: influxdb

I'm trying to count the occurrences of the same value using InfluxQL.

I have the following, when I run `SELECT distinct("name") from "table"`

```
1970-01-01 01:00:00 | value 1
1970-01-01 01:00:00 | value 2
1970-01-01 01:00:00 | value 3
1970-01-01 01:00:00 | value 4
```

I am able to see the occurrences of each value when I run `SELECT count("name") FROM "table" WHERE "name" = 'value 1'`

```
1970-01-01 01:00:00 | 239
```

What I would like to end up with is the above but for each name.

```
1970-01-01 01:00:00 | value 1 | 239
1970-01-01 01:00:00 | value 2 | 137
etc.
```

If I run `SELECT "name" FROM "table" GROUP BY "name"` then I have all of the values in one large result, so it's just how I count them from there.

I would also like this to change with the time interval.